# Generic Type contraints with Or

Tags: c#, constraints, generics

```
public T CreateForm<T>() where T: BaseForm, BaseMainForm
```

I know the above means where T is a `BaseForm` **and** a `BaseMainForm`. But is it also possible to make the constraint that T has to be either a `BaseForm` **or** a `BaseMainForm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not allowed in C#. The compiler uses the generic constraint to determine what operations is available on `T` within the generic method - so allowing an *or* expression would not be type safe.

If you need this, consider adding an interface covering the common parts of `BaseForm` and `BaseMainForm`, and apply that as the generic constraint. This way, the interface defines the contract of what the method `CreateForm<T>` needs - and you must simply make sure that the Form's you pass in implement the interface.

Something like:

```
public interface IBaseForm 
{
    Foo();
}

class BaseForm : IBaseForm {}
class BaseMainForm : IBaseForm {}

public T CreateForm<T>() where T : IBaseForm
```

Comment: Clear and fast answer! Thanx!

Comment: It gets much harder if you are not in control of BaseForm  or BaseMainForm so can't amek them implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

Consider adding either an interface or a base class, have both of those classes implement it, and use that as the type constraint.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need to extract the properties, that CreateForm is interested in, of BaseForm and BaseMainForm into a new interface that they both inherit from and then your method will reference that interface